# The Problem is :Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm actually stuck solving this problem. It gives me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined". When i used foreach loop everything goes fine but using normal for-loop gives me this error and i don't know why.

here is the code using javascript

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const pads = document.querySelectorAll(".pads div");
    const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound");
    var numberOfPads = document.querySelectorAll(".pads div").length;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPads; i++) {
        pads[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            sounds[i].play();
        });

    }

});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<body>
    <section class="app">
        <header>
            <h1>Beatmaker</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="visual">
            <div class="pads">
                <div class="pad1">
                    <audio class="sound" src="sounds/bubbles.mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
                <div class="pad2">
                    <audio class="sound" src="sounds/clay.mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
                <div class="pad3">
                    <audio class="sound" src="sounds/confetti.mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pads">
                <div class="pad4">
                    <audio class="sound" src="sounds/glimmer.mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
                <div class="pad5">
                    <audio class="sound" src="sounds/moon.mp3">
                    </audio>
                </div>
                <div class="pad6">
                    <audio class="sound" src="sounds/ufo.mp3">

                    </audio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. It happens because **`i` is function-scoped**, meaning that one and the same `i` is used for any point inside your function. This also applies to things running in the future. The loop *modifies* `i`, and when the loop is done, `i` will be 1 higher than the maximum value.

Let's go through this step by step - in the order in which things happen. For clarity: I see 6 divs, so we have valid values of `i` from 0 to 5 (including).

- Your `load` event handler executes:

  - `i` is 0. Your loop body runs because 0 is less than 6.
  - The statement `pads[i].addEventListener("click", ...)` executes with `i == 0`
  - `i` is 1. Your loop body runs because 1 is less than 6.
  - The statement `pads[i].addEventListener("click", ...)` executes with `i == 1`
  - ...
  - `i` is 5. Your loop body runs because 5 is less than 6.
  - The statement `pads[i].addEventListener("click", ...)` executes with `i == 5`
  - `i` is 6. Your loop body *doesn't* run because 6 is not less than 6.
- You click a div, say `pad4`.

  - The `click` handler runs (the one that was set when `i` was 3).
  - However, since we always talked about the same `i` here, **`i` is now 6** (see the last step from before!).
  - The line `sounds[i].play()` runs, attempting to access `sounds[6]`
  - Since `sounds[6]` is undefined, you cannot read its property `play` and you get an error.

The reason it works with a `forEach` is that it uses a callback, and that means that the `i` you access in there is the argument to your callback function, which is **local to the specific function invocation**. So you essentially get a new `i` every time, which keeps its value also in the future (it is never modified). You essentially get 6 different `i`s this way, not 1 `i` that changes its value over time!

If you want to keep using a `for` loop, you have to **use `let` instead of `var`**:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPads; i++) {
  // ...
}
```

This is because `let` creates a **block-scoped** variable. I know it is a bit confusing now how this can work, since `i` is still getting modified, but this is due to a special convenience behavior with `for` in combination with `let`: It actually creates two `i`s here, one that is modified every time (the one you see inside the `for (...)` parens) and one that is created as copy from the modified one on every iteration (the one you see inside the loop body).

If you are getting confused by this, another way to (more logically) solve the problem would be to manually assign `i` to a block-scoped copy inside the loop:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const pads = document.querySelectorAll(".pads div");
    const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound");
    var numberOfPads = document.querySelectorAll(".pads div").length;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPads; i++) {
        const j = i; // Create local copy
        pads[j].addEventListener("click", function () {
            sounds[j].play(); // Now we use j here and not i
        });

    }

});
```

(I used `const` to emphasize that it won't and even *can't* be modified, but `let` would work as well. Just `var` won't!)